# Derivation of divergence

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, differentiation, vector-fields

I was reading about the theory of electromagnetism and got stuck here:

[image]

I am getting confused with this Taylor series expansion. Though I know how to expand the series about a point $P$, but in the diagram, I am not understanding why while calculating the surface integral over the front surface $A_x$ has been taken to be only a function of $x$ whereas $A_x$  can be a function of all the three variables.

Can anyone explain this to me ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could produce a better quality image.  Why not try to look for one on the web?  It might also point you towards an answer to your question?

Comment: I have attached a new photo. Hope this would do.

Comment: I cannot read the image, but based on what you have said the author has chosen to create a vector field that increases in $y$, but is constant in $x$ and $z$.   Is that right?  If so, there is no problem.  That's a perfectly good vector field.  Can you explain why you are stuck?

Comment: I have changed my question acc to the new image which I could afford.

Comment: Sorry ,I wrote X and Y .I should have written X and Z

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the flux $\vec A\cdot d\vec S$

For the front face $d\vec S= dy\,dz \,\hat x$

Since the flux is a dot product the only component of $\vec A=A_{\rm x} \,\hat x + A_{\rm y} \,\hat y+A_{\rm z} \,\hat z$ which produces a non zero value is $A_{\rm x}$.

So $\vec A\cdot d\vec S=A_{\rm x}\,dy\,dz$

Using the value of the x-comment of the vector at $x=x_o$ you need to use the Taylor expansion to find the value of this component at $x=x_o+\frac{\Delta x}{2}$.

This is the step you were uncertain about but what you must notice is that a partial derivative with respect to $x$ was used.

By definition this means that $y$ and $z$ are kept constant.

---

I do not know why your derivation bothered with the Taylor expansion because without doing the expansion in the end you get terms like $\dfrac{A(x+\frac {\Delta x}{2})-A(x-\frac {\Delta x}{2})}{\Delta x}$ using your book's notation.
In the limit as $\Delta x$ tends to zero this, by definition, is $\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial x}$.

[You may find this link of use?](http://www.math.ups.edu/~martinj/MultivariableCalculus/CourseMaterial/Divergence.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

$V_y$ can also increase in the $x$ and $z$ direction but in our problem we are only interested in the increase of $V_y$ in the $y$ direction.

Why?

Because $V_y$ is perpendicular to X and Z axis and cannot contribute to the flux leaving the cube in the X and Z direction.(Remember the definition of flux).

The problem is not whether $V_y$ can increase with $x$ and $z$ or not,the problem is whether it matters when calculating flux or not.